# Cisco UCS manager logon credentials

Tags: networking

I have downloaded **Cisco UCS** manager from Cisco.  When I connect to it from the GUI I am asked for username and password. I think this must be the `user: admin` and `password: admin`, however I am getting an error stating that I have entered the wrong credentials.

Can anybody help me about this problem?

Comment: We can't possibly tell you the username and password for your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/gui/config/guide/1-3-1/b_UCSM_GUI_Configuration_Guide_1_3_1/UCSM_GUI_Configuration_Guide_1_3_1_chapter9.html#concept_1913301249134771510)

> Each Cisco UCS instance has a default user account, admin, which
> cannot be modified or deleted. This account is the system
> administrator or superuser account and has full privileges. There is
> no default password assigned to the admin account; you must choose the
> password during the initial system setup.

This means, without knowing anything about Cisco UCS, that you already gave a custom Password, during the installation

Comment: thanks for your attention, In fact I have download UCSPE,this is vmx format and will be booted in VM- machine. I have been allowed just to initialize IP and Gateway addresses, I have no any option to choose Password,  is here another solutions or way ? Thanks again

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/cli/config/guide/1-3-1/b_CLI_Config_Guide_1_3_1/CLI_Config_Guide_1_3_1_chapter41.html#concept_E60849794C7A4235BD41F5B319AF62CA